# SQL-server delete duplicates complex query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-delete

I am working at this query for days. So I have a database and the server should be updated one per day. If it is updated twice or 3 times per day then I have duplicates. I can find duplicates through a DATETIME value Date_Inserted. There is also an other DATETIME value the date updated. I can understand when I have duplicates, it is when I have more than 300 records and I can find it through this query:

```
  SELECT Date_Inserted, Date_Last_Updated, COUNT(Date_Inserted) 
    FROM   dbo.[Yacht&Sail_Analytical]
    GROUP BY Date_Inserted, Date_Last_Updated
     HAVING COUNT(Date_Inserted) > 300
```

Moreover when I want to see when the duplicates happened, I can find it through this query:

```
 SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT Date_Last_Updated, Date_Inserted, COUNT(*) AS Expr1
    FROM     dbo.[Yacht&Sail_Analytical]
    GROUP BY Date_Last_Updated, Date_Inserted
    HAVING (Date_Last_Updated = '2015 - 12 - 10 00:00:00.000')
    ORDER BY Expr1 DESC.
```

So as I just want to delete the records that were created at a specific day at a specific time, the ones that I can find from the SELECT queries, I am using this

```
DELETE  
FROM dbo.[Yacht&Sail_Analytical]
WHERE Date_Last_Updated NOT IN 
(SELECT Date_Inserted, Date_Last_Updated, COUNT(Date_Inserted) 
             FROM dbo.[Yacht&Sail_Analytical] LEFT JOIN
             (SELECT Date_Last_Updated, Date_Inserted, COUNT(*) AS Expr1
                FROM     dbo.[Yacht&Sail_Analytical]
                GROUP BY Date_Last_Updated, Date_Inserted
                HAVING (Date_Last_Updated = '2015 - 12 - 10 00:00:00.000')) AS ID
                )
)
```

which is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Error message:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9 Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: Missing join condition for the left join?

Comment: HAVING (Date_Last_Updated = '2015 - 12 - 10 00:00:00.000')) AS ID => last ) should not be there I think. Or it's the one after AS ID that shouldn't

Comment: I just tried without both and I still get the error. But thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I worked on this a bit more. My query was not correctly built. What worked for me was:

```
DELETE
FROM dbo.[Yacht&Sail_Analytical]

WHERE
(
MONTH(Date_Inserted)=12 AND   
YEAR(Date_Inserted)=2015 AND
DAY(Date_Inserted)=11) 

 AND 
[a/a] IN 
( SELECT [a/a] 
FROM dbo.[Yacht&Sail_Analytical]
WHERE Date_Inserted > CONVERT (DATETIME,'2015-12-11 16:00:00.457'))
```

Which is much simpler. *

> a/a is a unique ID for every row.

  *